# Functional programming with very math-like syntax

Tags: math, functional-programming

My background is computer science, exclusively in imperative programming (C/C++, Python). Since I'm currently struggling with coming up with a formal description for some algorithms for a paper, I was wondering if there is a functional programming language that provides a syntax as close as possible to mathematical notation; for example, similar to what Event-B is offering (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaXu0.png for a screenshot), but without the overhead (State Machines, etc) Event-B has.

My use case for this is simple: I'd like to be able to come up with a formula like

[image: formula]

and enter this, with a syntax as close as possible, into the programming language to evaluate it with different inputs and check if it really does what I expect it to. Therefore, performance or reusability are no concerns for me.

I do realize that I could implement those functions in any programming language such as Python, but that would again require me to interpret them while translating them to that language, where I'd most probably make the same interpretation mistakes I already did when coming up with the original formula.

Comment: `def initial_plus(r): return set([initial(r)]).union(*[initial_plus(r2) for r2 in regions(initial(r))])` in Python is not close enough to the mathematical formulation?

Comment: @MvG: in theory it is close enough, but since my background CS rather than math, I'm afraid that using Python I might miss subtle differences between Python's (and probably mine) and 'conventional' math semantics.

Comment: So you do not only want a *language* which *allows* syntax like the one above, but also a *library* (which might come with the language) which *supports* syntax like this. Which isn't obvious from your question, so you might make this more explicit. That said, I doubt there is *any* language without subtle differences to mathematical notation. This statement includes mathematical notation itself, since a lot there depends on context.

Answer (score 2):

There are no mainstream languages with 2D syntax (e.g. your subset operation underneath the union operation).

There are many languages with unicode operators however, e.g. [Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unicode-prelude/0.1.1/doc/html/Prelude-Unicode.html#6)

Answer (score 2):

[Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/) allows to work with the usual mathematical 2D syntax, do symbolic operations and also allows to convert the result into C or FORTRAN. This capability makes it not bad as a developer tool for tasks where specifications include some complex math.

[Matlab](http://www.mathworks.ch/products/matlab/) allows to program in a graphical way with 2D syntax but unlike Maple it locks everything in its environment so is more a researcher tool.

Comment: Thanks, Maple looks promising, I will give it a shot.